# Why is the ampersand an invalid character in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I am using the method `Escape` from the `SecurityElement` C# class to make sure some of the text I received can be safely integrated in an XML document later.

I just [noticed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.escape?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) that the & character is considered invalid.

**Question**

I understand how the other characters can mess up an XML document and make impossible to parse but I do not see why an & would.

Comment: How is `<` encoded in XML, according to https://coderstoolbox.net/string/ ?

Comment: & is used to start an entity like &gt; which represents < etc.

Comment: `I just noticed that the & character is considered invalid.` Look just to the right of where you noticed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `&` is used to denote an XML entity. It's used as the "escape" character for other invalid characters (e.g. `&lt;` meaning `<`), so it can't itself be a valid character in XML. How could you tell whether `&` was an ampersand, or the beginning of `&gt;`?

In order to express an ampersand in XML, you need to use `&amp;`.

---

This is similar to the way, in C (and similar languages), where `\` is used to escape `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), etc., and must itself be escaped as `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

From the referenced document it shows that the ampersand is used as part of escaped code for other codes such as > is `&gt;` etc, so it would get confused if it was valid on its own.

Comment: same answer  23 secs earlier :)