# How to remove special characters from an XML output?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm facing an issue of **special characters** being added to output payload whenever i'm doing transformation to xml. see below sample for your reference.

I want to populate the exact **value** whit no special characters being added. As well, is there a function to be applied to trim and remove special characters from payload in case of any?

**Input Payload**

```
{
  "Order" : {
    "Id" : 215,

    "Line" : [ {
     "Desc" : "d&Bf 5489-lk45 brand apple 13 pieces",
      "buyerDesc" : ""
    }
    ]
    }
    }
```

**Used Dataweave Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml escapeGT= true
---
{
    "Order": {
        id: {
    Detail:  {
    Line: payload.Order.Line map {
      
    frame:{
Desc: $.Desc,
DescDeatails: $.buyerDesc
    }
  }
    }
}}}
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Order>
  <id>
    <Detail>
      <Line>
        <frame>
          <Desc>d&Bf 5489-lk45 brand apple 13 pieces</Desc>
          <DescDeatails/>
        </frame>
      </Line>
    </Detail>
  </id>
</Order>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single ampersand (`&`) character is [invalid in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008682/721855). The resulting document would not be able to be parsed in any correct XML parser. DataWeave automatically encodes that character into the right sequence `&amp;`. No need to add `escapeGT` or any directive. When an XML parser reads that sequence it will convert it back to a single ampersand. This is the recommended method to use ampersands in XML.

If for some reason that is not acceptable you can convert that field to a CDATA value where it would be valid to have the single ampersand. That would make sense for values that contain code though I don't see any reason to do so in a description text.

Example: `Desc: $.Desc as CData`

Comment: great. That have answered my doubt